# Azure search scoring profile on list

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Having a list of string as a property of my index, using scoring profile, is it possible to boost a result based on an element contained in the list?

Comment: Not right now, but we're looking into this so some more specifics would be useful. In your case, the list had a set of elements, what do you compare against? A fixed value in the scoring profile? A value passed as separate parameter at query time? A search string match?

Comment: The property I would like to score are : City - Edm.GeographyPoint / Friends - Collection(Edm.String) (list of identifiers) / LastActive - Edm.DateTimeOffset.  And I would like to score it by distance + last active + if in friend list boost the search result. The 2 first one are already achievable by freshness and distance but the last one I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: Got it. The question is what are you going to compare the friends list against. If the friend list is just a searchable field, you could include it as part of the search string and adjust the weight of the field as needed, but I suspect that that's not what you're trying to achieve. In the case of distance, the location is measured against a search request parameter, do you want to compare the list of friends against one or more names also given as search request parameters separately from the actual search string?

Comment: I will compare the list with one Id. It is a searchable field but I do not want to "search it" as I want the result "sorted". Meaning the users with the particular Id in the list of friend will be boosted. As I understand, a search will only give me users which contains the particular Id in their list. The list will only be compared to one Id.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify. As I mentioned in the first comment we don't have a way to model this exactly right now but were looking at extending scoring functions to handle this and hearing your scenario is useful to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Search didn't have this capability at the time the question was asked, but we heard similar scenarios (all around results personalization in one way or another) so we added a way to model this with scoring profiles.

The new "tag boosting" capability in scoring profiles can do this now.

More details in this [blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/05/personalizing-search-results-announcing-tag-boosting-in-azure-search/).

Comment: Is there any further documentation on this scenario? I couldn't find any documentation aside from that blog about the format. Is it comma delimited, are there any limits, etc?